# flutter problem:how to set column in bottomNavigationBar of scaffold?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Here In this code I used column , in last column i used button and text. This column i want to use in bottomNavigationBar of scaffold.

### When i am using column in bottomNavigationBar then i got ui problem as you can see in screenshot.

When i am using column in bottomNavigationBar then i got ui problem as you can see in screenshot.
this is my code.

```
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/Constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/UIs/DialogPages/session_expire_page.dart';
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/UIs/OnBoard/LoginPage/enter_num_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AccountTypePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountTypePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AccountTypePageState createState() => _AccountTypePageState();
}

class _AccountTypePageState extends State<AccountTypePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: lightBlue,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/account_logo.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 325,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Choose from account type.",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: tSize30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: skyBlue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "Use Guest Login if you just want to do a application trial.",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: tSize14,
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

// from here this column I want to use in bottomNavigationBar of scaffold

                Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20.0, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: skyBlue,
                              shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => EnterNumPage()));
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: const [
                              Opacity(
                                opacity: 0,
                                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                              ),
                              Text('Login / Register'),
                              Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(onTap: (){
                      showDialog(
                          useRootNavigator: true,
                          barrierDismissible: false,
                          barrierColor: skyBlue.withOpacity(0.4),
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return SessionExpirePage();
                          });
                    },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Login as Guest",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: tSize14,
                              color: darkGreyColor,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

// Here I want to use that column part

    bottomNavigationBar: Column(children:[]),
    );
  }
}
```

after using that column in bottomNavigationBar then
[image]

Comment: try  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, property in column. It may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the property in the column to-

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```